# Angular excitations and Schrodinger operators with radial potential

Tags: soft-question, mathematical-physics, spectral-theory, sturm-liouville

Can someone please explain the following in mathematical language? What are angular excitations and s-waves mathematically?

"First of all, angular excitations only push the energy up, never down, so it is enough to analyze spherically symmetric s-waves...", c.f. first answer in
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/370901/solution-for-inverse-square-potential-in-d-3-spatial-dimensions-in-quantum-mec

Edit: change in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you solve the central force Schrodinger equation, you can use separation of variables, that is, you assume that the solution is a product of a term that is purely radial ( = dependent on the distance $r$ from the central force origin) and purely angular , i.e. dependent purely on the angles $\phi, \theta$. This gives eigen-solutions that have the form $\Psi=A(r)B(\phi, \theta)$. Once this is done, it is natural to consider solutions where the angular term is a constant, that is $\Psi = A(r)$. These are the S waves. "Angular excitations" are how the angular terms affect the solution eigenvalues.

Comment: Thanks! The assertion about the increase of the energy also seems true in general dimensions (not only 3D), cf. the short comment here, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366830/angular-excitations-and-schrodinger-operators-with-radial-potential-in-n-dimensi?noredirect=1&lq=1.